# I want to get loop result of these emails using jQuery, here's my code :

Tags: jquery, loops

```
var Email=["name@google.com","name@yahoo.com","name@gmail.com"];

function winner(){
    for(var i=0;i<Email.length;i++){
        Email[i]+=i;    
        $("#winner").text(Email[i]).fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(3000).delay();    
    }
}
setInterval(winner,1000);
```

Comment: but not working , it'll output all the emails2222222 and emails333333333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with this:

1) `Email[i]+=i;` is appending the value of `i` onto the email address, hence why it outputs lots of integers

2) On each execution of the function you loop through all the emails, but you don't see all of them happen because of the fade time vs the interval - the function is being re-run 5 times for every one fade in/out sequence.

Something like this should work better:

```
var Email=["name@google.com","name@yahoo.com","name@gmail.com"];
var i = 0; //set a counter

function winner() {
  $("#winner").text(Email[i]).fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(3000);
  i++; //increment the counter
  if (i >= Email.length) { i = 0; } //reset the counter
}

winner(); //initial display at load
setInterval(winner,5000); //run every 5 seconds subsequently, to match the fade timing
```

See it working in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5f0o4zxx/3/

Comment: only remove the var from i++ when //increment the counter line

Comment: oops, sorry, that was a typo. corrected now - thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Email[i]+=i;
```

doesn't have too much sense. Also, your setInterval calls function every second, but you have fadeIn/fadeOut together - 5 seconds, so that will not work fine, too.

You could do something like this:

```js
var Email=["name@google.com","name@yahoo.com","name@gmail.com"];
i=0; //init
$("#winner").text(Email[0]).fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(3000).delay(1000); //init
setInterval(function(){ 
i++;  
$("#winner").text(Email[i]).fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(3000).delay(1000);
if(i==Email.length-1) { //if you want loop
i=-1; //reset counter
}
}, 
6000); //every 6 seconds
```

```css
#winner {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="winner">

</div>
```

Code is commented, so you can see what's happening.